# display all objects

Tags: django

I'm new to django. I'm trying to display all post from post model. But its not working. please help me. `'now':now` is working fine. thanks

```
def display_all_post(request):
   now = datetime.datetime.now()
   posts = Post.objects.all()
   return render_to_response('index.html',{'posts':posts,'now':now})
```

here is my template

```
    {% for post in posts.object_list %}
        {{post.title}}
        {{post.body}}
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove object_list attribute from posts in the template:

```
 {% for post in posts %}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you take the time to go through the queryset and templating sections of Django documentation.